# Не записывает нечётные имена в массив

Tags: java, массивы, динамические-массивы

Ниже код простого авто-турнира котов: вбиваем количество участников - получаем результат их стычек. Суть проблемы - Коты с нечётным постфиксом не записываются во второй промежуточный массив? Почему? Буду рад, если хоть в общем опишите источники проблемы с указанием строк, а также направите почитать по конкретным темам для устранения таких неурядиц в дальнейшем)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Solution {
private static int mastercount=0;

private static ArrayList<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    int round = 1;

    int cc=0;
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while(cc==0) {
        cc = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());
    }
    bf.close();

    String[] names = {"Котик","Киса"};

    for (int i = 0; i < cc; i++) {
        cats.add(new Cat(names[(int)(Math.random()*2)]+(i+1),(int)((Math.random()*15)+1),(int)((Math.random()*8)+1),(int)((Math.random()*10)+1)));
    }


    while(mastercount>2 || mastercount==0){
        checkMassive(cats,round);
        round++;
    }
    System.out.println("THE END");//Проверка окончания работы
}

public static void checkMassive(ArrayList<Cat> c,int r){
    int mascount=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {
        if (c.get(i).fightCount == 0) {
            if(i!=c.size()-1) {//если не последняя последняя ячейка
                if(c.get(i).fight(c.get(i+1))) {
                    if(c.size()>2) System.out.println("Round "+r+" winner: "+ c.get(i).name);
                    else System.out.println("!!!ABSOLUTELY WINNER!!!"+c.get(i).name+"!!!ABSOLUTELY WINNER!!!");
                    c.get(i).fightCount++;
                    c.get(i+1).fightCount--;
                    mascount+=2;
                }
                else {
                    if(c.size()>2) System.out.println("Round "+r+" winner: "+ c.get(i+1).name);
                    else System.out.println("!!!ABSOLUTELY WINNER!!!"+c.get(i+1).name+"!!!ABSOLUTELY WINNER!!!");
                    c.get(i+1).fightCount++;
                    c.get(i).fightCount--;
                    mascount+=2;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(c.size()>2) System.out.println("Round "+r+" INDIVIDwinner: "+ c.get(i).name);//добавил в текст INDIVID, для простоты анализа отображения появления единственного участника в раунде
                else System.out.println("!!!INDIVIDABSOLUTELY WINNER!!!"+c.get(i).name+"!!!ABSOLUTELY WINNER!!!");
                c.get(i).fightCount++;
                mascount+=1;
            }
        }
    }
    Cat[] tmp = new Cat[c.size()];//создаём временный массив для выбора победителей - пробывал ArrayList - тоже самое
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {//Не записывает победителей ТОЛЬКО с нечётными именами
        if(c.get(i).fightCount==1) {
            c.get(i).fightCount=0;
            tmp[i] = c.get(i);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {//проверка того - что записалось
        if(tmp[i]!=null)  System.out.println(""+tmp[i].name);
    }

    Solution.cats.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        if(tmp[i]!=null){
            Solution.cats.add(tmp[i]);
        }
    }
    Arrays.fill(tmp,null);
    mastercount = mascount;

}
public void setCats(ArrayList<Cat> a){

}

public static class Cat {

    public static int count = 0;
    public int fightCount = 0;

    protected String name;
    protected int age;
    protected int weight;
    protected int strength;

    public Cat(String name, int age, int weight, int strength) {
        count++;

        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.strength = strength;
    }

    public boolean fight(Cat anotherCat)
    {
        fightCount++;
        double a,w,s,p1;
        if(anotherCat.age<10 && this.age<10)  a = this.age - anotherCat.age;
        else{
            p1 = this.age;
            if(anotherCat.age>9) anotherCat.age = anotherCat.age/(((anotherCat.age-9)/10)*4+1);
            if(this.age>9) p1 = this.age/(((this.age-9)/10)*4+1);
            a = p1 - anotherCat.age;
        }
        if(anotherCat.weight<7 && this.weight<7)  w = this.weight - anotherCat.weight;
        else{
            p1 = this.weight;
            if(anotherCat.weight>6) anotherCat.weight = anotherCat.weight/(((anotherCat.weight-6)/10)*3+1);
            if(this.weight>6) p1 = this.weight/(((this.weight-6)/10)*3+1);
            w = p1 - anotherCat.weight;
        }
        s = this.strength - anotherCat.strength;
        p1 = a+w+s;
        if (p1>0)return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Замените данный блок:

```
if (c.get(i).fightCount > 0) {
    c.get(i).fightCount = 0;
    tmp[i] = c.get(i);
}
```

Дело в том что ваши котики получают очков боя больше чем одно) - мухлюют.Обратите внимание вы изменяете значение переменной `fightCount` в том числе и в методе бой()...

Comment: Спасибо большое - я просто слепой идиот) - такая тупая ошибка. Правильно меня минуснули - просто стыдоба.

Answer (score 2):

Захардкодьте себе переменные котов. 
Как я понимаю это имя и параметры возвраст, вес, сила.
В этих рандомах запутаться можно.

В методе fight() 
просто сравнивайте, например эти 3 параметра и за каждый давайте по очку одному или второму коту. если у первого будет больше очков - возвращайте тру.

А раунды можно выщитывать например так:

```
 System.out.println("Схватка между Барсиком и Мурзиком...");
        if (cat1.fight(cat2))
            System.out.println("Победу одержал Барсик");
        else
            System.out.println("Победу одержал Мурзик");
```